# How to create new collection in Cloud firestore dynamically?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to create a new Subcollection inside an already existing collection in cloud firestore using some code via my flutter application.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Firestore.instance.collection('oldCollectionName').
document("insideCollectionNameNode").setData({
      'yourKey': "yourValue"
    }).then((result){
      print("result");
    });
```

1. "oldCollectionName" is your existing collection name,
2. "insideCollectionNameNode" is your new sub collection name,
3. "yourKey" is your key data inside sub collection data.
4. "yourValue" is your value data inside sub collection data.

Comment: i am using this, but the changes doesnt reflect in the firestore untill I make a collection of that name manually myself.

Comment: Update your question with database image,what actually you needed.